# .htaccess url rewriting - what do I do wrong?

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am getting into .htaccess URL rewriting. I can't elaborate following:

I am altering between two conditions

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?action=$1

RewriteRule ^(.*)/([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?action=$1&product_id=$2
```

Used on same sample url **http://www.my-domain.cz/products/5**

In my php script I call `echo var_dump($_GET)` to see what's in there after rewriting.

For first rule I am getting: `array(1) { ["action"]=> string(9) "index.php" }`

For second rule I am getting: `array(2) { ["action"]=> string(8) "products" ["product_id"]=> string(1) "5" }`

What is wrong with the first rule, that it only shows "index.php" (and regardless the given url). I believe the round brackets in regular expression should take everything after first slash ("products/5") and fill it into $_GET["action"] field, so I can work with that later in PHP script. Why is that not happening? And what is so different in the second rule, that here it works as expected?

Btw: First rule is taken from an article about "nice urls" and it *should* do what I have written. But apparently, it doesn't.

Comment: Your first rule rewrites everything, also existing files on the server like `index.php`. You should add conditions to only rewrite non-existing files and directories.

Comment: Or simply put the second rule before the "catch all" rule and append `[L]` to the line. See http://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/mod-rewrite/